# Will a tensorflow model give different results if trained in a previous version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tensorflow

I have a tensorflow model trained in tf version 1.1 and python 2.7. I'm running it in tf version 1.10 and python 3.6. After feeding the same data into the model in both versions, the outputs are slightly different. Of 512 outputs, 7 do not match. Is this a versioning issue, or something else? I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your Tensorflow code may contain internal random number generator, you might check if you forgot to seed the random generator with the tf.random.set_random_seed(seed) function.